# How to switch my ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web app to development mode while in AWS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I recently developed a new web application with ASP.NET Core 5 MVC. On the local IIS web server, the apps runs fine and can connect to the database.

On AWS beanstalk, however, I only get a note that says I have to be in development mode.

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Are you sure the message isn't telling you that *detailed exception messages* are only displayed in development mode? In which case, the question should really be how you get hold of the error logs to diagnose the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the environment properties inside the aws console to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development`, if you are sure that your app should be running in Development mode.